# subprocess in python3 calling C script failed on " has Failed. Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, subprocess

I have a tool in python that works fine on old virtual machine, which its default python version was 2.7 and gcc version 4.5.2
I got another new virtual machine default/supported python version is 3.7.4 and default gcc version is 4.7.2. I'm trying to run my tool on new machine and I'm getting error
"**has Failed. Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**" on the following line :

*subprocess.Popen(cmd_str, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)*

the tool supposed to call a script written in C

how can I fix this?
thanks!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Is it possible to run the "C"  program executable standalone (in the new environment) from  a shell and check out if it executes properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: gcc version 4.7.2 does not support the command "addr2line". I changed the version to 4.9.2 and it worked